# Sign out a devise session from custom controller action (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How to Sign out of a devise session from a custom controller?

Do we have any inbuilt function to do this? just like we have for `user_signed_in?`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a `sign_out` method in Devise. You can call it without parameters. See [doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_out-instance_method).

Answer (score 8):

Can just clear the sessions:

```
reset_session
```