# Signout from a controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I want to signout from a controller. My controller looks like

```
def update
if @attendance.update_attribute(:logout_at, Time.now.localtime)
  redirect_to signout_path and return
end
end
```

And my routes looks like

```
  devise_scope :employees do
     get "signout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"

  end

  devise_for :employees, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

But It gives error

> Unknown action
>
> Could not find devise mapping for path "/signout". This may happen for
>   two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block.
>   For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" =>
>   "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller
>   bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which
>   mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] =
>   Devise.mappings[:user]

How can I do that? Please Help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sign out a devise session from custom controller action (Rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162077/sign-out-a-devise-session-from-custom-controller-action-rails)

Comment: I tried that. But unfortunately it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redirecting, which makes a GET request to `devise#sessions#destroy`, a route that doesn't exist. The `signout` route in Devise is a mapped to a DELETE request. Instead of redirecting you should [directly call the `sign_out` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_out-instance_method) that Devise makes available to you. After that be sure to redirect the user somewhere, maybe the login page.

A side note, in Rails 4 you can call `update(attribute: value)` directly. You don't need to call `return` either.

```
def update
  @attendance.update(logout_at: Time.now.localtime)
  sign_out
  redirect_to login_path      
end
```

I removed the if statement that wrapped the update call. By using one you are implying that there maybe a reason the save will not happen because of validation error, for example, and you need to provide feedback to the user. But in this case it's more likely to be an exception since there is no data input by the user. You can handle that at the application level.

Comment: after putting **sign_out** I got another error _Missing template attendances/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/srabon-megh/RailsProjects/CT_Attendance/app/views" * "/home/srabon-megh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.8/app/views" * "/home/srabon-megh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views" _

Comment: Actually I want to update a field in the table and then destroy the session. For that I used a signout like `<%= link_to "Sign out", attendance_path(present), :method => :put %>` And it goes to update action and then I want to destroy session.

Comment: If you just want to update a field, you can try inheriting devise session controller and do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854994/rails-devise-sessions-controller

Comment: @Muktadir well, after signing out the user you need to do something. The action will try and render a view by default, in this case it will look for `edit.html.erb`, which does not exit. So simply redirect to the desired location after signing out the user. I'll update my answer.