# Sign user out in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've created functionality to allow a user to delete their account from my app, that works.  However, at the end, I'm trying to automatically log the user OUT which would send them back to the sign in page.

I've tried various things which I thought would work, but my controller is throwing an error saying that I don't have the view in place for the Controller method:

> Missing template subscriptions/cancel_subscription

```
def cancel_subscription
 ...a bunch of code that clears out the user's info
 redirect_to destroy_user_session_path      
end
```

I'm using `Devise`, so the routes are default:

```
new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
user_session POST   /login(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session GET    /logout(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
```

How do I go about automatically logging the user out since they don't actually have any account data anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def cancel_subscription
  #code to cancel
  sign_out current_user
  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

inside `cancel_subscription`

Comment: So, that's still throwing the error that a view doesn't exist.

Comment: You'll probably want `redirect_to root_url` at the end of `cancel_subscription`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer help with your situation: [Sign out a devise session from custom controller action (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162077/sign-out-a-devise-session-from-custom-controller-action-rails)

There is a `sign_out` method provided from devise. Once you sign the user out, you can then redirect them to a proper action with a valid template (root, etc).

Hope that helps.